# Bash/JQ - parse error: Expected separator between values at line 1, column 63

Tags: bash, jq

I'm having what I suspect is a quoting error in a bash script.

```
SECRET_VALUE_CMD="curl -s -L -H \"X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN\" -X GET \"https://$VAULT_ADDR/v1/secret/$secret_path\""
SECRET_VALUE_RESPONSE=$(eval $SECRET_VALUE_CMD)
SECRET_VALUE=$(echo "$SECRET_VALUE_RESPONSE" | jq --raw-output '.data.value')
```

When I execute this in my script, I get the following to stderr:

```
parse error: Expected separator between values at line 1, column 63
```

and $SECRET_VALUE is blank.

An example of $SECRET_VALUE_RESPONSE is:

```
{"request_id":"XXXX-YYYY..,"lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":nnnnnn,"data":{"value":"secret-value"},"wrap_info":null,"warnings":null,"auth":null}
```

I've tried adding escaped quotes around the parameters to eval and echo, but can't seem to find a working combination. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `eval`? Why in the world? (See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a discussion of better practices, and [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for a specific discussion of why `eval` is dangerous -- **especially** dangerous when passing it data that comes off the network).

Comment: Also, note that all-caps variable names are used by variables with meaning to the shell or OS, per [POSIX-specified convention](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) (see fourth paragraph), whereas code using lowercase variable names is guaranteed not to unintentionally modify behavior of POSIX-specified system components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `eval`. You could create a function to execute `curl`, for example:

```
get_secret_value() {
    curl -s -L -H "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" -X GET "https://$VAULT_ADDR/v1/secret/$secret_path"
}

secret_value=$(get_secret_value | jq --raw-output '.data.value')
```